# Improving list comprehension so that it runs faster

Tags: python, list, performance

I'm creating a Goldbach conjecture which outputs the two prime numbers with the highest product. As it stands once the input is a large number, it takes a ridiculously long time to solve.

```py
def prime_pair_solution(n):
    def isprime(n):

        n = abs(int(n))
        if n < 2:
            return False
        if n == 2: 
            return True
        if not n & 1: 
            return False

        k= int(n**0.5)+1
        for x in range(3, k, 2):
            if n % x == 0:
                return False
        return True

    count=(int(n/2)+(int(n/4)))

    y=[(p2,p1)for p1 in range (2,count) for p2 in range(p1,count) if isprime(p1) and isprime(p2) and (p1+p2)==n]
    return y[-1]
```

Comment: It is better to improve your isprime function. Replacing naive prime search method with the Sieve of Eratosthenes will drastically speed up your code. List comprehension is implemented in very efficient way. You can check that replacing it with the loop in your code.

Comment: Yuri's comment is mostly right that the big performance problem with your code is the prime test. But there is one thing that can speed your list comprehension up a bit. You don't need two loops. If you generate one prime `p1`, the second number `p2` needs to be `n-p1`, so you could just do a prime test on that, rather than finding all primes and seeing if one of them added to `p1` gives you `n`. It's still going to be slow, but not *as slow* as what you're doing now.